# Deploy directory to Azure Cloud Service even if it's not included in the project

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I want to deploy my node_modules folder to Azure Cloud Service but I don't want to include it in my project because it's very large and is making my project slow.

Is there a way to add a configuration to deploy it even though it is excluded in the project?

Answer (score 0):

As we know, to deploy an application as a cloud service in Azure, we must first package the application in the appropriate format (ServicePackage.cspkg). And from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps), we could find:

> Azure Cloud Services expect all modules to be installed on the development environment, and the node_modules directory to be included as part of the deployment package.

you had better to [include these files in your VS project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-publishing-a-cloud-service#include-files-in-the-service-package) before you publish project as Cloud Service. Or you could try to [use cspack command line tool to package a cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-model-and-package#servicepackagecspkg) and drop files to role folder to make files include in your cloud service package.

Besides, It is possible to enable support for installing modules using package.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json files on Cloud Services, please see [Azure Startup task to run npm install to avoid deploying node modules](https://github.com/woloski/nodeonazure-blog/blob/master/articles/startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure.markdown) to know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Is there any basic documentation on how to use the cspack command? Nothing I tried seems to work. Mostly the error I'm getting is that it couldn't find the Web project: `Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/'`